# Finding unit of WWII soldier that fought in Italy

Tags: military-records, world-war-2

Where do I look to find out what unit my uncle was assigned to and where his unit fought in WWII. I do know he was in Italy at one point

I have his serial number:  39614088
He enlisted (was drafted) on 17 Nov 1942

Comment: Which Service are we talking about? UK, USA, Axis?

Comment: You don't mention his name, which branch of military, which country he's from or anything else that is useful. That doesn't look like any UK service number I've seen.